Mixed emoji and plain text font in Flutter?
I'd like to mix text and emoji with the minimum of effort. (e.g. to render user-supplied messages). However, I'm having problems finding a straightforward way to do that short of examining every piece of text and replacing it with separate textspans having different fonts (e.g. see the answers here Displaying text with Emojis on Flutter -- with is pretty awful for editable text). Taking the following for example:

With this font, plain text is incorrectly rendered. Without it, the emojis are incorrectly rendered as a black block with and x through it (web).
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';

void main() {
  return runApp(content());
}

Widget content() {
  return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'NotoColorEmoji view',
        theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: 'NotoColorEmoji'),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Text("☝️Letter Shape⭐️⭐️☝️⭐️⭐️☝️⭐️⭐️☝️⭐️⭐⭐️"), //const MyHomePage(),
      ));
}

flutter:
  fonts:
     - family: NotoColorEmoji
       fonts:
         - asset: assets/fonts/Noto/NotoColorEmoji-Regular.ttf



Refer my answer hope its help to you. 1, 2. Or if you can used Android studio for flutter development then try to Windows + . button it will shows you emojis pop up select your emoji and just click it it full fill your widget.

I believe there are some issues with that Noto emoji font. I just tested, and I've got the same spacing issue. I'd never seen it before. I tried different fonts - Roboto, Open Sans, Lato, Montserrat, Poppins, Raleway & etc. All are working as expected.
      theme: ThemeData(
        textTheme: GoogleFonts.notoEmojiTextTheme(),      // Not working,
        textTheme: GoogleFonts.notoColorEmojiTextTheme(), // Not working,
        textTheme: GoogleFonts.robotoTextTheme(),         // Working,
        textTheme: GoogleFonts.openSansTextTheme(),       // Working,
        textTheme: GoogleFonts.latoTextTheme(),           // Working,
        textTheme: GoogleFonts.montserratTextTheme(),     // Working,
        textTheme: GoogleFonts.poppinsTextTheme(),        // Working,
        textTheme: GoogleFonts.ralewayTextTheme(),        // Working,
      ),

Visit this website to find trending fonts: https://fonts.google.com/analytics.

Do any of those that are working support color emojis? (robotoTextTheme does not).

I wrote, "Hello!  My name is Dharam ". And I can see coloured emojis in all of them (Noto ones have some spacing issues).

Did you try with a web target?

No, I have not. I believe the result would be the same. It's a font issue, not a platform issue.

The behavior of fonts is different on web vs native.
I have programs where color emojis are shown in native and Linux and black and white shown on web.

You can split the text into regular and emoji.
Then you can use different fonts.
import 'package:sequence_processor/sequence_processor.dart';
import 'package:unicode/emoji/emoji.dart';

void main(List<String> args) {
  const str = '☝Letter Shape⭐⭐☝⭐⭐☝⭐⭐☝⭐⭐⭐ ';
  print(str);
  final parts = _decompose(str);
  print(parts);
  for (final element in parts) {
    final font = element.$1 ? 'EmojiFont' : 'RegularFont';
    print(
      'Font: $font "${element.$2}"',
    );
  }
}

// Should be stored in a static member for performance reasons.
final _processor = () {
  final emojis = getUnicodeEmojiList();
  final processor = SequenceProcessor<int, Object>();
  for (final emoji in emojis) {
    processor.addSequence(emoji.codePoints, emoji);
  }

  return processor;
}();

List<(bool, String)> _decompose(String text) {
  if (text.isEmpty) {
    return [];
  }

  final elements = _processor.process(text.runes.toList());
  final result = <(bool, List<int>)>[];
  (bool, List<int>)? regular;
  (bool, List<int>)? emojis;
  for (final element in elements) {
    if (element.data is Emoji) {
      regular = null;
      if (emojis == null) {
        emojis = (true, []);
        result.add(emojis);
      }

      emojis.$2.addAll(element.sequence!);
    } else {
      emojis = null;
      if (regular == null) {
        regular = (false, []);
        result.add(regular);
      }

      regular.$2.add(element.element!);
    }
  }

  return result.map((e) => (e.$1, String.fromCharCodes(e.$2))).toList();
}


Output:
☝Letter Shape⭐⭐☝⭐⭐☝⭐⭐☝⭐⭐⭐
[(true, ☝️), (false, Letter Shape), (true, ⭐⭐☝️⭐⭐☝️⭐⭐☝️⭐⭐⭐), (false,  )]
Font: EmojiFont "☝️"
Font: RegularFont "Letter Shape"
Font: EmojiFont "⭐⭐☝️⭐⭐☝️⭐⭐☝️⭐⭐⭐"
Font: RegularFont " "


Honestly, that sounds like an enormous pain in the butt - I mean, I could use icons and images instead of emojis too. But the point of emojis is that you can treat them as text. Surely there's a way to display both text and emojis together without having special-case the creation of widgets.
